# Does cache block get overwritten when tags mismatch?

Tags: cpu-architecture, memory-address, cpu-cache

I am trying to understand how CPU cache works. Consider an example from Udacity's [High Performance Architecture course](https://classroom.udacity.com/courses/ud007/lessons/1225208558/concepts/12117686182589030923). The processor has a 4KByte, direct-mapped, write-back, write-allocate, physically indexed, physically-tagged data Ll cache with 256-byte blocks. The cache starts empty, and the following instructions are executed in a sequence:

```
LD 0x0000ABFD
ST 0x0000ABFC
ST 0x0000AB7C
LD 0x0000BCEC
LD 0x0000ACEC
ST 0x0000BCEC
```

Address breakdown for cache access is:

1. tag (bits 31 through 12)
2. index (bits 11 through 8)
3. offset (bits 0 through 7)

Thus, the sequence of cache accesses is the following:

```
 tag  |idx|offs| hit or miss 
-----------------------------
0000A | B | FD | Cache miss since it's empty
0000A | B | FC | Cache hit since the index and the tag match
0000A | B | 7C | Hit 
0000B | C | EC | Miss (tag mismatch)
0000A | C | EC | Miss (tag mismatch)
0000B | С | EC | ?? Hit (0000B|С is still in the cache) ??
```

It seems to be clear, except the last row. In my understanding when `LD 0x0000ACEC` accessed cache (and got a miss due to the tag mismatch), it should have updated the cache entry at index C, including the tag, so the subsequent `ST 0x0000BCEC` should no longer see the tag 0000B, but 0000A and get a cache miss. But it looks like my view is wrong. Could somebody explain what actually happens when accessing an existing cache index with a different tag?

Another question, when we update cache entries do we update the whole cache block or just a value corresponding to the cache block offset? E.g. `LD 0x0000AB11` followed by `LD 0x0000AB34`.

Is there any difference in terms of caching between load and store accesses?

Comment: Your view looks correct to me. Tag should be updated upon 0xACEC and we should have a mismatch with the subsequent 0xBCEC.

Comment: Both of 0xAB11 and 0xAB34 match to the same 256 byte block and hence the second load be just be a hit. (Unless you have a sector cache, then it will still be a tag hit but data for the particular sub-256 block will have to be fetched from main memory). For stores we do writes at 4B/8B granularities whereas we can load at either 256B or 4B/8B  (with sector caches) granularity

Comment: *Is there any difference in terms of caching between load and store accesses?*  For normal CPU caches, generally they're designed to treat a store miss basically the same as a load miss (allocate new line, fill from backing store).  But a cache without write-allocate is also possible, i.e. store misses basically bypass the cache.  (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cache_(computing)#Writing_policies).  IDK if there are any workloads where that's useful for a write-back cache; you might only find it in a write-through cache (where write-allocate is only useful for store/reload or spatial locality)

Comment: The last access in the sequence is a load, but the text talks about "the subsequent ST 0x0000BCEC." Also, is there any information in the question about what cache coherence protocol is used? You'll get a store miss even if the tags match when the coherence state doesn't allow modification.

Comment: Looking at the Udemy link provided, I can confirm @HadiBrais comment that the last `LD 0x0000BCEC` appears as `ST 0x0000BCEC` on the course.

Comment: @HadiBrais My bad, the last instruction is store. I have just corrected it. But it doesn't seem to change anything. Or does it? 

Cache coherence protocol doesn't seem to be mentioned in the question.

Comment: Is it required that these accessed must be performed sequentially, i.e., the next one cannot start until the previous one completes? If not, you could get a hit under a miss. For example, the line at index C may only be evicted when the new line has reached the cached. Meanwhile, it could service other requests to the same line. This would explain how the last one can be a hit.

Comment: @HadiBrais I suppose the access is performed sequentially for there is a phrase "the processor executes the following sequence of accesses"